# Mounted VeraCrypt drive does not show up in WSL

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, veracrypt

I found [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/530). But it isn't working for me. I mount a VC volume as I: (for example), and /mnt/i is "No such file or directory".

According to one claim in that thread, closing down all WSL dialogs should do the trick. Doesn't work for me.

According to another, it is necessary to format the volume NTFS. Duly done. Again, doesn't work for me.

Anyone had any luck with this? Incidentally this WSL2, W10 Version "10.0.19042" aka "20H2".

Comment: **TL;DR:** `wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 --bare` or whatever drive, in PowerShell, then run `wsl` command to open WSL itself. Then install veracrypt CLI in WSL, then run `lsblk` to see which drive, then run `veracrypt -m=nokernelcrypto /dev/sdc2` or whatever. It will ask you for your password and such. Finally, it will be mounted in `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\media\veracrypt1` or whatever.

Comment: In my case, I had to `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt install libfuse2`, and then install the VeraCrypt CLI manually. Then it would run with just `veracrypt`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is possible, when running the latest WSL2 preview version, to mount in WSL ext4 volumes encrypted with VeraCrypt. The procedure to follow is described at: https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/027f5f92bf/

Comment: Thanks... have since discovered restic, an amazing snapshotting backup app, which is cross-platform, encrypted throughout, etc. So have no need for WSL or VeraCrypt any more!